# A single line command to take and print the user's input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to echo the user input in a single line. Multiline way:

```
set /P name="What Is Your Name?"
echo %name%
```

Below doesn't work.

```
set /P name="What Is Your Name?" & echo %name%
```

Comment: try to use two `&`s

Comment: No, `&&` won't help, but [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) will. Alternatively, use `set /P name= & call echo %%name%%` in a batch script or `set /P name= & call echo %^name%` directly in Command Prompt...

Comment: Replacing `&` by `&&` would prevent the `echo` command from being executed when the user enters nothing and just presses *{Enter}*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another layer of expansion as the parser reads the line before `%name%` has been defined with a value. You therefore need to delay the expansion, using one of a few methods.

This *ab*uses the `Call` command:

```bat
@Set /P "name=What is your Name? " && (Call Echo Welcome %%name%%) & Pause
```

And this uses delayed expansion more correctly:

```bat
@Set /P "name=What is your Name? " && (SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Echo Welcome !name! & EndLocal) & Pause
```

This one uses another instance of cmd.exe with its delayed expansion option:

```bat
@Set /P "name=What is your Name? " && (Cmd /V /C Echo Welcome !name!) & Pause
```

And this uses a `For` loop to perform similarly:

```bat
@Set /P "name=What is your name? " && (For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%G In ('Set name 2^>NUL') Do @Echo Welcome %%H) & Pause
```

Comment: This also works: `set /P name="What Is Your Name?" & for /F %%a in ('echo %%name%%') do echo %%a`

Comment: Thanks @Aacini, I've now added an example using a slightly different [tag:for-loop] for the expansion, _just to keep things more varied_.

Comment: @aschipfl, I have additionally modified the examples to use the conditional `&&` instead of the concatenating `&`, as mentioned in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017696/a-single-line-command-to-take-and-print-the-users-input/60017964#comment106145470_60017696).

Comment: @Compo `@Set /P "name=What is your Name? " && (Cmd /V /C Echo Welcome !name!) & Pause` is perfect.1st one works only for the first time though enough for my use case. 2nd one gives "Welcome !name!". 4th one gives "%%G was unexpected at this time."

Comment: I've no idea how you've implemented them, @tejasvi88, but they should all work as written in single line batch files.

Comment: @Compo I am testing them directly on cmd.

Comment: @tejasvi88, your used tags along with your question did not specify how you were running the command, so I answered with my best assumption. Luckily at least one of my examples was suitable for your purposes.